# How to send an OpenNI depthmap via boost asio to client?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, kinect, openni

im trying to send a kinect depthmap to an client via boost asio (without serializtion)
is it better to try asynch or synch (for now my approach ist synch):

smthg like this..

```
server:
//depthmap
const XnDepthPixel* pDepthMap = depth.GetDepthMap();
boost::asio::write (socket, boost::asio::buffer (pDepthMap, sizeof(pDepthMap))); //sizeof isnt right..

client:
XnDepthPixel* depth;
socket.read_some( boost::asio::buffer (&depth, sizeof(XnDepthPixel)* ?? )); //send sizeof(pDepthMap) before..
```

EDIT:
the definition of XnDepthPixel (also from OpenNI):

```
/** Defines the depth values type (16-bit values). **/
typedef XnUInt16 XnDepthPixel
```

and XnUInt16:

```
/** 16-bit unsigned integer. */ 
typedef unsigned short      XnUInt16;
```

Comment: async or synchronous does not matter. You need to convert a XnDepthPixel object into a stream of bytes. Can you edit the question with the definition for XnDepthPixel?

Comment: ok.. the def. is added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(pDepthMap)` is just size of the pointer, but what you actually want is to send some structure, not a pointer to it.

Please, take a look at ASIO *Serialization* [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.serialization) to see how it can be done using Boost.Serialization.
If you don't want to use Boost.Serialization, you can "serialize" your structure by your own, in some proprietary way.

Comment: thx for your answer.. serialization lib is no option, i guess.. 

for now i don't know how to get to real data (not as pointer) so i saved them in an extra array.. seems to work (not so efficient, but with wifi this loop isn't adding any time)